# How can I make this rewrite rule so that it can accept querystring?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a url rewrite rule that uses map method.

```
            <rewriteMap name="Pages">
                <add key="/search" value="/search.asp" />
            </rewriteMap>




            <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for Pages">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{Pages:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

My problem is when I use this page like below, I get error:

/search?keyword=math

I get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:85/search?keyword=math
Physical Path      D:\webs\V5ST\HTML\search
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

How can I make this so that whatever querystring is passed to search.asp?

Comment: Could tell us what is your exact requirement?

Comment: when I enter http://localhost:85/search?keyword=math on address bar, I want it to rewrite /search.asp?keyword=math

Comment: In fact not just tat I want it to pass whatever querystring typed to search.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="query string redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="search\?(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:132/search.asp?{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Regards,
Jalpa